# Node.js - tcp server close event handler is not working

Tags: node.js

Why is end event handler(socket) and close event handler(server) is being called at the same time?
I am expecting close event handler to be called after 30 seconds.

Can someone please help me?

Although after 30 seconds my TCP server is not accepting any new connection(keeps existing connections open) but I was expecting close event handler invocation after 30 sec.
close event handler of server as well as end event handler of socket is invoked when I forcefully close all existing tcp clients.

TCP connection ended
TCP connection ended
server closed but it will keep existing connection

```
var net = require("net");

function getSocketInfo(socketObject){
                    console.log('bytesRead= ' + socketObject.bytesRead);
                    console.log('bytesWritten= ' + socketObject.bytesWritten);
}

var tcpServer = net.createServer({allowHalfOpen:false},function(socketObject){
                socketObject.setEncoding('utf8');
                getSocketInfo(socketObject);
                socketObject.on('data',function(data){
                        console.log('data received');
                        console.log(data);
                        console.log(data.length);
                        socketObject.write('Server Reply: ' + data,'utf8',function(){
                        console.log('data successfully written on socket');
                        });
                        getSocketInfo(socketObject);
                        });

                socketObject.on('end',function(){
                        console.log('TCP connection ended');
                        });
                });

setTimeout(function(){tcpServer.close();},30000);

tcpServer.on('close',function(){ console.log('server closed but it will keep existing connection');});

tcpServer.on('error',function(error){
                console.log(error.code);
                });

tcpServer.listen(8000,function(){
                console.log('TCP server has been bound');
                });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer after looking into the event section.

close handler will be called when ALL EXISTING TCP connections are closed, not immediately after close method invocation. This was strange but as per documentation it is correct behavior.

Event: 'close'#

> Emitted when the server closes. Note that if connections exist, this
>   event is not emitted until all connections are ended.